# Allowing cross domain requests with Express JS and HTML5 fetch()

Tags: javascript, express

How can I allow cross domain requests with an ExpressJS server and Javascript's fetch? I think this might be an issue with `fetch()` from the client because `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is in the response's headers.

I added this code but it still doesn't work:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost:4200"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

I noticed the request headers don't include anything about COR:

```
Accept  
text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   
max-age=0
Connection  
keep-alive
Host    
localhost:4200
If-None-Match   
W/"2ef-TFWfb4ktmG8ds+qhoRRzEvmkPdY"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   
1
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; …) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
```

The front end code:

```
export function createHttpObservable(url: string) {

    return Observable.create(observer => {

      fetch(url, {mode: 'cors'})
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(body => {
          observer.next(body);
          observer.complete();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          observer.error(error);
        })

      });

  }
```

Error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:9000/api/courses. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The localhost URL is not proper. Please change like below.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
next();
```

});

Comment: I've got this is response header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cors middleware https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html